# "talk something over" vs discuss

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between "talk over" and discuss?

- Let's **discuss** it.
- Let's **talk** it **over**.

Could you please provide a case where you woul use one but not the other?

Comment: No difference. "Talk it over" is an idiomatic expression for "discuss it."

Comment: Some dictionaries seem to give them as synonyms, but to me _talk over_ has definite implications of discussing a _problem_ or difficult situation, not just any topic. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/talk-sth-over

Comment: Thank you for the answers!